# Convolution Integral involving an unknown function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

I've got the following problem I'm working on which is related to some of my research.

I am trying to solve the following equation for the function $f$.

$$t^{-\alpha} \exp{ \left(- \beta  x^2 t^{-2 \alpha} \right)} = \int_0^t \frac{f\left(x, s\right)}{t - s}ds$$
where $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ and $\beta=\alpha \Gamma \left(\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ are some non negative constants.

I have tried to take Laplace and Fourier transforms of the left hand side, but to no avail. Is there any other strategy to obtain $f$ ?
I am stuck here, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there a problem with convergence of the integral at s=t?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy ... That right-hand side is known as a "singular integral".  There is a vast literature on that.

Comment: It is a one-sided integral, so it cannot be interpreted as a Cauchy principal value. What am I missing?